# Want to create function validating textbox with letters only

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

And another function to validate specific format like " ad12-XYX- 123-EFD-20"

I have created the function for numbers only'  I want something similar to this

```
Private Sub AllowNumericonly(Byval CTRL As control)
    if not Isnumeric(ctrl.text) And Ctrl.test<> "" Then

       MSGbox("Please enter numbers only." , Vbinformation)
       ctrl.text = ""
       ctrl.focus()
     End if 
End sub
```

Please help!

Comment: Use REGEX. `IsNumeric`, blah blah - this is not hoing to help

Comment: I try to use REgex but not allowing me and giving me error if Input REGEX. also e.keychar are giving the error, as not defined...

Comment: If you tried to use a `Regex` and it didn't work then you did it wrong.  If we don't know what you did or what the error message was then how can we know what you did wrong?

Comment: I am try to use regex into my coding, but when I am typing REGEX, its not giving me any option for it, as its exist , same with "e."

Comment: I am working in Winforms VB,  not doing vb.net, I am fairly new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method that will detect only letters but there is far more to your problem than just that.

```
Private Function IsAllAlpha(text As String) As Boolean
    Return text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetter(ch))
End Function
```

Notice that I have written a `Function` rather then a `Sub`.  Your original method is poorly written.  What you should actually be doing is handling the `Validating` event of the control, validating the control contents in that event handler and then setting `e.Cancel` to `True` if it fails, in which case the control will retain focus.  The validation can be done in place or with a method that takes in a `String` and returns a `Boolean`.  For example:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
    e.Cancel = Not ValidateTextBox(TextBox1, AddressOf IsAllAlphaOrSpace, "Please enter only letters or spaces.")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.Validating
    e.Cancel = Not ValidateTextBox(TextBox2, AddressOf IsAllNumeric, "Please enter only numeric digits.")
End Sub

Private Function ValidateTextBox(textBox As TextBox, validator As Func(Of String, Boolean), errorMessage As String) As Boolean
    Dim isValid = validator(textBox.Text)

    If Not isValid Then
        textBox.SelectAll()
        textBox.HideSelection = False

        MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Invalid Input", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        textBox.HideSelection = True
    End If

    Return isValid
End Function

Private Function IsAllAlphaOrSpace(text As String) As Boolean
    Return text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetter(ch) OrElse ch = " "c)
End Function

Private Function IsAllNumeric(text As String) As Boolean
    Return text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsDigit(ch))
End Function

Private Function IsAllAlphaNumeric(text As String) As Boolean
    Return text.All(Function(ch) Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch))
End Function
```

If you really want to validate the complex format that you indicated then you might consider using a `MaskedTextBox` or else use a `Regex`.  I'm not much of an expert in that but finding out how should be fairly easy for just letters and digits.

Comment: your code make sense, but I  think it going in loop, as well not allow to enter space and backspace, also after entrying int input not allow to progress further, in next text box.  where as in my code I am getting all the functionality i want,, But Your code is good idea...

Comment: "I think it going in loop", you think wrong. "not allow to enter space and backspace", backspace is not an issue because it's not a character in the final text and you didn't say that you wanted to allow spaces but the code could easily be modified to do so. "after entrying int input not allow to progress further", that's actually the point, i.e. don't let the user move on unless they have entered appropriate data.  Why would you want to let them?  You can allow it with designer configuration if you really want to though, so it's not an issue.

Comment: Thanks buddy appreciate your response, But even when I input correct int  still its not progressing further, that why I think its in loop.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I was incorrectly setting `e.Cancel` in the `Validating` event handlers.  I've modified the code to fix that.  I have also modified the letter validation to allow spaces to show how it can be done.